# How to use case when with parameter sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a case when statement in my store procedure showed below

```
select distinct case 
                  when e.emp_type = '' or e.emp_type is null then 'A' 
                  when @emp_type = 'A' Then e.emp_type = 'A' 
                  else e.emp_type
                end as emp_type
from t_gc_emp e
```

Let say the emp_type is the type of employee such as part time, full time, contract, etc. I am not sure what I did wrong here, but when I try to execute the store procedure, it said

> Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: What kind of DB is it?

Comment: Are you trying to assign a value to the table `when @emp_type = 'A' Then e.emp_type = 'A'`?

Comment: @jarlh, yeah, and I have updated my mistake,

Comment: Eh? `Then e.emp_type = 'A'` - are you wanting to return a boolean value here? Or perform an assignment? Whatever follows a `THEN` should be an expression that computes a value, but I can't make sense of that one.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in your second when, namely it should be when `@emp_type = 'A' Then 'A'` instead of `when @emp_type = 'A' Then e.emp_type = 'A'`.

You could try running the following

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
            case when e.emp_type = '' or e.emp_type IS NULL then 'A' 
                 when @emp_type = 'A' Then 'A' 
                 else e.emp_type end   as emp_type

FROM t_gc_emp e
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign field value to anything in the `case` expression, but you can output it via `select`:

```
when @emp_type = 'A' then 'A'
```

Or even better:

```
select distinct case 
                  when e.emp_type = '' or e.emp_type is null or @emp_type = 'A' then 'A'  
                  else e.emp_type
                end   as emp_type
from t_gc_emp e
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your second THEN -> THEN e.emp_type = 'A' .

```
 SELECT DISTINCT  
        case when e.emp_type = '' or e.emp_type IS NULL then 'A'  
             when @emp_type = 'A'  then 'A'
             else e.emp_type
       end   as emp_type
  FROM t_gc_emp e
```

BTW - If it suppose to look like this, why another WHEN? combine it inside the first WHEN

```
 SELECT DISTINCT  
        case when @emp_type = 'A' or e.emp_type = '' or e.emp_type IS NULL then 'A' 
             else e.emp_type
       end   as emp_type
  FROM t_gc_emp e
```